# Shilov Linear Algebra 6.63

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am still ploughing my way through Shilov's Linear Algebra and I have discovered that Chapter 6 is a watershed from which the learning curve is markedly steepened.

[image]

I cannot understand what is $P(\lambda)$ be an annihilating polynomial of $P(\lambda)$. And also how does the equation $P(\lambda)$ come about?

And how does this relate to the equation in 6.62?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo. The polynomial $P(\lambda)$ is the annihilating polynomial of $A$.

Comment: I doubt if it is a typo. Thanks for your confirmation. But I have no idea on how to get this equation.

Comment: Note that the sentenc which first mention $P(\lambda)$ begins with “Let $\mathbf A$ be a linear operator in a real $n$-dimensional space $\mathbf R_n$, and let $P(\lambda)$…”, but the rest of the sentence has to $\mathbf A$ in it. That makes no sense.